# pylons route with period

Tags: python, pylons, ckan

I am currently trying to make a once static page into a dynamic page.  The customers does not want to change the url to not have the .html at the end of the url. So, as an example the current static page is `/foo/bar.html` which is located in my public folder, no problem.  I can easily make it `/foo/bar`, but once I have a period pylons no longer excepts the route.

current code:`map.connect('foo', '/foo/bar.html',controller=controller , action='foo')`

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that all I needed to do was add {.format} and rename the original file because pylons with route to the static page first!